# How to create a diff file from gazebo development version

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I downloaded the gazebo development version and I'm working on it. How can I create a diff file of all gazebo package (including the sourcecode) to see my changes and easily make a patch??

I downloaded the simulator gazebo from:
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/simulator_gazebo-1.2 ~/simulator_gazebo/

Added the new simulator gazebo path to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and build. It takes like 700 seconds and then all is OK, in build folder is all the source code.

If I do a "svn st" all the folders are with a "?"
If I do a svn info it returns:

Path: . URL: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/simulator_gazebo-1.2/gazebo
Repository Root: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg
Repository UUID: eb33c2ac-9c88-4c90-87e0-44a10359b0c3
Revision: 38270
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: hsu
Last Changed Rev: 37935
Last Changed Date: 2011-09-16 22:44:55
+0200 (Fri, 16 Sep 2011)

And if I do a svn diff it don't return anything (even if a made some changes in the source code). What am I doing wrong? or what is the proper way of do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12067/how-to-create-a-diff-file-from-gazebo-development-version/) by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 370 on 2011-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I already found the answer to my own question, when you are working with development versions, the source code package is donwloaded when you do a rosmake, in my case if you go to simulator_gazebo/gazebo folder, it should be a "Makefile.gazebo.trunk" this file contain all the information required to building the code. There is the location of the source code repository. In my case is in:

SVN_URL = https://playerstage.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/playerstage/code/gazebo/trunk

You can do a "svn co" of this repository, add your changes and then do a "svn diff", this will return you a patch file from gazebo source code. I did this to attach this patch to a gazebo defect ticket with IRSensor https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/trac/ticket/30

---

Originally posted by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) with karma: 370 on 2011-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0